# How can i encode a pdf file to base64 string in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Unable to convert a pdf file to `base64` in android pie, file path returns is **"content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/4402"** which is not real path hence `unable to access the file`.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to encode a pdf file to base64  string

Comment: No, that's not your question. That's your goal. Your question is how to get the correct file path for a pdf file

Comment: Right please help me on that

Comment: I can't without seeing your code

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
fun convertToBase64(attachment: File): String {
    return Base64.encodeToString(attachment.readBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use the following whole class into our project to get the real path, I got the solution to my problem

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/FileUtils.java

After that, I have used the following code to convert pdf file to encode to base64 string

`fun convertToBase64(attachment: File): String {
    return Base64.encodeToString(attachment.readBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
}`

Answer (score 1):

Support for `file:///path` uris was discouraged and later on dropped.

You need to use a `ContentResolver` to access a `content://auth/path` uri.